# mac build has undefined symbol where linux build did not for same code

Tags: c++, gcc, undefined

We have gcc 4.2 for mac, and gcc 4.4 for linux. When I build the same code, I get the following undefinded symbol:

"MyClassNameSpecific1::MyClassNameSpecific1(int, int, int,  className::class1 const&, className::class2 const&, int, int)", referenced from:
      MyOtherClassName::mContainer()       in MyOtherClassName.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

The code looks like this for MyClassName.h:

```
class MyClassNameSpecific1;
class MyClassNameSpecific2;

class MyClassNameSpecific1
{
  public: 
    MyClassNameSpecific1(const string &param1);
    virtual ~MyClassNameSpecific1() {}
}
class MyClassNameSpecific2: public classU::UData 
{

public:
    MyClassNameSpecific2(int width, int height, int breadth, const className::class1 &dType, const className::class2 &layout, int tWidth, int tHeight);
};
```

The MyClassName.cpp has this:

```
#include "MyClassName.h"

MyClassNameSpecific1::MyClassNameSpecific1(const string &param1) : classU::UData()
{
    //does things here
}

MyClassNameSpecific2::MyClassNameSpecific2(int width, int height, int breadth, const className::class1 &dType, const className::class2 &layout, int tWidth, int tHeight) : classU::UData()
{
    //does things here
}
```

I'm not sure what could cause the undef in one but not the other.  Is anyone aware of a difference in gcc for this kind of situation? My makefile has all: MyClassName then other classes. I don't see any differences in the parameter signatures between .h and .cpp file for MyClassNameSpecific2.

I tried making sure I used the complete className::class1 in both the .h and .cpp files, but it still had the same undef.  Also, I tried adding class MyClassNameSpecific2, where it only had class MyClassNameSpecific1 at the top of the MyClassName.h file, but it didn't change the undef.  I tried googling the problem, but nothing pertinent turned up.  Maybe there's another thing I could have searched for, but I'm not sure.  I left out #includes for the little class definitions in my .h and .cpp file.

That would be great if anyone had something to try, even if it's a different nomenclature for the parameters that I didn't think of.

Added makefile:

```
.SUFFIXES: .cpp

DEP_DIR = ../dependencies

CC = g++

OS := $(shell uname -s)
ifeq ($(OS),Darwin)
   #set LIB_DIR
   LIB_DIR1=darwin64_gcc42/lib
   LIB_DIR2=darwin64_gcc44/lib
else
   LIB_DIR=linux64_gcc44/lib
endif

INCDIRS = -I. -I../include \
        -I$(DEP_DIR)/className/include \
        -I$(DEP_DIR)/classNameOther/include

#C++FLAGS = -c -fPIC -g -O2 -DLINUX -D_DEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -m64 -Wall
C++FLAGS = -c -fPIC -O2 -DLINUX -DNDEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -m64 -Wall

ifeq ($(OS),Darwin)
    LDFLAGS = -m64 -pthread -ldl -shared -L../$(LIB_DIR1)/release \
        -L$(DEP_DIR)/className/$(LIB_DIR1) \
        -L$(DEP_DIR)/classNameOther/$(LIB_DIR2)/release
else
    LDFLAGS = -m64 -pthread -ldl -shared -L../$(LIB_DIR)/release \
        -L$(DEP_DIR)/className/$(LIB_DIR) \
        -L$(DEP_DIR)/classNameOther/$(LIB_DIR)/release
endif

LDLIBS = -llittleClass -lclassName -lclassNameOther -lclassNameOthermalloc

all:    MyClassName MyOtherClassName AnotherClass2 AnotherClass3 AnotherClass4 AMoreOverallClass

AMoreOverallClass: AMoreOverallClass.o
    $(CC) AMoreOverallClass.o $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(LDLIBS)

...


.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(C++FLAGS) $(INCDIRS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf *.o all
```

Here is make output at command line:

```
mcle@engmacvi01(577)% make
g++ -c -fPIC -O2 -DLINUX -DNDEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -m64 -Wall -I. -I../include -I../dependencies/className/include -I../dependencies/classNameOther/include MyClassName.cpp -o MyClassName.o
g++ MyClassName.o -m64 -pthread -ldl -shared -L../darwin64_gcc42/lib/release -L../dependencies/className/darwin64_gcc42/lib -L../dependencies/classNameOther/darwin64_gcc44/lib/release -o MyClassName-ludm -lclassName -lclassNameOther -lclassNameOthermalloc
g++ -c -fPIC -O2 -DLINUX -DNDEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -m64 -Wall -I. -I../include -I../dependencies/className/include -I../dependencies/classNameOther/include AnotherClass.cpp -o AnotherClass.o
g++ AnotherClass.o -m64 -pthread -ldl -shared -L../darwin64_gcc42/lib/release -L../dependencies/className/darwin64_gcc42/lib -L../dependencies/classNameOther/darwin64_gcc44/lib/release -o AnotherClass -llittleClass -lclassName -lclassNameOther -lclassNameOthermalloc
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "MyClassNameSpecific1::MyClassNameSpecific1(int, int, int, className::class1 const&, className::class2 const&, int, int)", referenced from:
      AnotherClass::mContainer()       in AnotherClass.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [AnotherClass] Error 1
```

Also, MyOtherClassName.cpp:

```
UReturnClass &MyOtherClassName::mContainer()
{
    if (!m_mContainerPtr)
    {
        m_mContainerPtr = new UReturnClass();
        UMPtr md = new MyClassNameSpecific2(m_width, m_height, m_bands, m_dataType, m_dataLayout, m_tileWidth, m_tileHeight);
        m_mContainerPtr->setMdata(md);
    }
    return *m_mContainerPtr;
}
```

MyOtherClassName.h:

className::class1 m_dType;
className::class2 m_dLayout;

Comment: *How* do you build on either platform?

Comment: make clean then make

Comment: So you have a makefile? Are you using the same makefile for both systems? Are there any differences in the makefile depending on system? Any conditional compilation (`#ifdef` or `#if`) you haven't told us about? If everything is *exactly* the same on both systems then you should not get an error like that. There must be *something* that differs (besides the operating system which shouldn't matter for this problem).

Comment: I added the makefile above with conditional ifdefs. I put ... instead of the generic names for the classes.

Comment: Please, provide compiler's console output, where one can see the full command line for each command executed during compilation.

Comment: I provided console output from mac compile. Cleaned up makefile with littleClass, className, and classNameOther.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the fact that MyClassNameSpecific2 specifies const in it's parameter, but the class that calls it doesn't?

Comment: Your error refers to `MyClassNameSpecific1` with the arguments from `MyClassNameSpecific2`'s constructor. Are you *sure* this is the code and the matching error?

Comment: @dascandy - no it doesn't.  If you look closely, MyClassName.h defines two classes in it, one of which is MyClassNameSpecific1 and the other is 2.  The 2 class has the longer signature.

Comment: @Michele If you look closer your error reads `"Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:  "MyClassNameSpecific1::MyClassNameSpecific1(int, int, int, className::class1 const&, className::class2 const&, int, int)", referenced from:
      AnotherClass::mContainer()       in AnotherClass.o"`. That's not in agreement with your code.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I see it now.  Fixed it in error in writeup.

Comment: Have you tried `-dynamiclib` rather than `-shared`?

Comment: It still has the undef if I use -dynamiclib instead of -shared after a clean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for this was to change the makefile so that it built it all in one step instead of separate steps for each class, since they were trying to link separately to get the .o file for each one, before putting it all together at the end. I'm not sure why the linux build was fine doing this separately and the mac build was not.  Class names changed to protect the innocent.

SRCS=UMetaPlugin.cpp UDataPlugin.cpp UForPlugin.cpp UFacPlugin.cpp UMTransPlugin.cpp UPlugin.cpp

objects=$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SRCS))

all: $(appn)

$(appn): $(objects)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(objects) $(LDLIBS)

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(C++FLAGS) $(INCDIRS) $< -o $@

Comment: This seems like a terrible way to write a makefile. Why are you even still using plain old handwritten makefiles? That being said, Linux is a lot more lenient on the matter of undefined symbols at link time, so perhaps that explains the discrepancy in behaviour.

Comment: We use cmake for the main part of the application but need a regular makefile for the client portion, because we can't ship the python cmake tools to them.